# accessing windows azure blob storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access my blog storage on Windows Azure but every time I browse to

```
http://my_storageAcount.blob.core.windows.net
```

it gengerates 400 error (bad request).
thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://my_storageAcount.blob.core.windows.net is the address of your Azure Blob Storage account.If you are trying to access the blob you need to specify the container name and the blob name.
Suppose, you have a blob by name "**MyBlob**" present in "**mycontainer**",you can retrieve it by specifying 
http://my_storageAcount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/MyBlob.

For other operations on Blob Microsoft has released REST api to work with Blob.to know more [Visit here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/).In case you are working with private blobs and stuck with accessing them in browser.you need to have Shared access signature for the Private blob to access them directly in the browser. For knowing more about Shared access signature Visit [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415)

Hope it helps.Happy Coding!!!